# ClassCastException encountered while using loginViewModel: androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry cannot be cast to androidx.activity.ComponentActivity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I add login and sign up functionality to android kotlin app and I encounter this error `ClassCastException` for using loginViewModel and signupViewModel in app navigation. How can I resolve this?

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.bettehomes.presentation.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.material.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.bettehomes.data.login.LoginViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.data.signup.SignupViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.GeoMarkerViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.navigation.AppNavigation
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.theme.BetteHomesTheme
import com.example.bettehomes.utils.locationFlow
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

  private val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient by lazy {
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
  }

  private val geoMarkerViewModel: GeoMarkerViewModel by viewModels()
  private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModels()
  private val signupViewModel: SignupViewModel by viewModels()


  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
      val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
      val navController = rememberNavController()
      BetteHomesTheme {
        AppNavigation(
          navController = navController,
          snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState,
          geoMarkerViewModel = geoMarkerViewModel,
          loginViewModel = loginViewModel,
          signupViewModel = signupViewModel,
          fetchLocationUpdates = this::fetchLocationUpdates,
        )
      }
    }
  }

  private fun fetchLocationUpdates() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
      lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        fusedLocationClient.locationFlow().collect {
          it?.let { location ->
            geoMarkerViewModel.setCurrentLatLng(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

NavHost:

```
package com.example.bettehomes.presentation.navigation

import androidx.compose.material.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import com.example.bettehomes.data.login.LoginViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.data.signup.SignupViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.GeoMarkerViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.screens.GeoMarkerScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.screens.LoginScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.screens.MapsScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.screens.SignUpScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.presentation.screens.TermsAndConditionsScreen

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun AppNavigation(
  navController: NavHostController,
  snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState,
  geoMarkerViewModel: GeoMarkerViewModel,
  loginViewModel: LoginViewModel,
  signupViewModel: SignupViewModel,
  fetchLocationUpdates: () -> Unit
) {
  NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.MapScreen.route) {
    composable(Screens.MapScreen.route) {
      MapsScreen(
        snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState,
        navController = navController,
        fetchLocationUpdates = fetchLocationUpdates
      )
    }
    composable(Screens.LoginScreen.route) {
      LoginScreen(loginViewModel) }
    composable(Screens.SignUpScreen.route) {
      SignUpScreen(signupViewModel) }
    composable(Screens.TermsAndConditionsScreen.route) {
      TermsAndConditionsScreen() }
    composable(Screens.GeoMarkerScreen.route) {
      GeoMarkerScreen(geoMarkerViewModel) }
  }
}
```